# BigQuery pure procedure is very slow

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I am exploring BigQuery procedures.
One of issues which worries me the most that
even pure code which doesn't work with anything else but a single local variable is super slow.

```
declare i int64 default 0;
declare l int64 default 1000;
declare started timestamp;
declare ended timestamp;

set started = current_timestamp();
WHILE i < l DO
set i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
set ended = current_timestamp();
select i, l, started, ended, timestamp_diff(ended, started, second);

-- 12 ms per iteration!!!
-- note that job scheduling is not included
```

The code above doesn't touch any table and doesn't cause any IO nor CPU cache misses.

How to make the code faster?

### Update 1

Just for comparison I run same code in plpgsql on https://sqliteonline.com/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mybenchmark(l int)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
  i int := 0;
  started timestamp;
  ended timestamp;
  ds float;
begin
  started := clock_timestamp();
  while i < l loop    
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
  ended := clock_timestamp();
  ds := EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (ended - started));
  raise  'Rate: % per second; Duration: % seconds; Per iteration: %', (l/ds), ds, (ds/l);
end;
$$;

call mybenchmark(1000000);
```

Speed is amazing:

> Rate: 7302041.650845577 per second; Duration: 0.136948 seconds; Per iteration: 1.36948e-07

Postgresql server for education purposes is 87624 times faster (0.012/1.36948e-7) than BigQuery production one.

Comment: The idea of a BigQuery procedure is to start SQL queries depending on variable values. Using a loop to do calculations is not the goal of it.

Comment: The given example is a bit academic, as adding only a counter up to 1000 is more of an example than a real world task. If in each iteration, another SQL query is started, which typically takes several  seconds to minutes, the 12 ms for couting are ignorable. If you need to do calculations, please do these inside one single SQL query.

Comment: If stored procedure contains 400 lines loop body then 1 iteration takes 4 seconds * multiple by 1^6 rows execution time becomes insane long. These stored procedures are not practical.

Comment: You are right, "these stored procedures are not practical" for doing large loops or complex calculations directly. These procedures are only there to start other SQL queries, depending on variable values. Use SQL statement, which even allows the use JavaScript UDF, to do complex calculations and calculations involving loops.

Answer (score 0):

The given code is BigQuery procedure with a loop. In BigQuery these procedure loops are quite slow and each step may take several ms.
As a rule of thumb, each statement (if, while, set) takes about 7 ms.
However, it is expected that in each loop a SQL query is called, which duration is typically between several seconds and minutes. So the 12 ms for the procedure duration can be neglected.

The best practice is to avoid procedure, which do not call other SQL statements. So the given code of this question can be written as JavaScript code. This  JavaScript UDF is called by a Select statement. The calculations are returned and saved to the values of the procedure by the "SET" command.

Put any calculation inside a Select SQL query. JavaScript UDF can be used.

```
declare i int64 default 0;
declare l int64 default 19000;
declare started timestamp;
declare ended timestamp;

set started = current_timestamp();
create temp function fun(i int64,l int64)
returns int64
language js as
"""
var tmp=i;
while(tmp < l ){
  tmp=tmp*1+1;
  }
return tmp;
""";
SET i = (Select fun(i,l) );

set ended = current_timestamp();
select i, l, started, ended, timestamp_diff(ended, started, second);
```

The given procedure code can be make worse by adding more calculations:

```
declare i int64 default 0;
declare l int64 default 1000;
declare c int64 default 0;
declare cc int64 default 0;
declare started timestamp;
declare ended timestamp;

set started = current_timestamp();
WHILE i < l DO
set i = i + 1;
set c = c + i;
if i>0 then 
set cc = cc + c;
end if;
END WHILE;
set ended = current_timestamp();
select i, l, started, ended, timestamp_diff(ended, started, second);
```

This will take over 30 ms per loop.

Replacing the set statement by

```
SET i = (Select i+1 );
```

will take 300 ms per loop,

```
SET i = (Select min(i+1+x+y) from unnest(generate_array(0,10000)) x, unnest(generate_array(0,10000)) as y );
```

will take  5 s.

Comment: as far as I know JS is not a option for defining procedures. Plus if so how to express out arguments?